# Group array of objects by common key (date string)

Tags: javascript

I have an array as below.

```
            const list = [
               {
                 date: "2020-01-01",
                 number: 3,
                 count: 2
               },
               {
                 date: "2020-01-01",
                 number: 3,
                 count: 2
               },
               {
                 date: "2020-01-01",
                 number: 3,
                 count: 2
               },
               {
                 date: "2020-01-02",
                 number: 4,
                 count: 1
               },
               {
                 date: "2020-01-02",
                 number: 4,
                 count: 1
               }
             ]
```

And I want to sum number and count depends on same date. After that it should be merged in same date. Therefore I want to get the result as below.

```
   const list = [{
     totalNumber: 9,
     totalCount: 6,
     detail:[{
             date: "2020-01-01",
             number: 3,
             count: 2
           },
           {
             date: "2020-01-01",
             number: 3,
             count: 2
           },
           {
             date: "2020-01-01",
             number: 3,
             count: 2
           }]
          },
      {
          totalNumber: 8,
          totalCount: 2,
          detail:[  
          {
             date: "2020-01-02",
             number: 4,
             count: 1
           },
           {
             date: "2020-01-02",
             number: 4,
             count: 1
           }]
         }
         ]
```

I know stackoverflow is not code writing site. But I made this from some data. But this is my last stage for completing my object. And I don't know how I can group like that. I'' appreciate if you help me to resolve this problem. Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: _"I know stackoverflow is not code writing site"_ - Lucky for you this type of "question" has already answers here on SO. You just have to search them -> _"javascript group array of objects"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, optimal approach is building [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) (having necessary property as a key) with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), then extracting array of values (aggregated records) with [`Map.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values):

```js
const src = [{date:"2020-01-01",number:3,count:2},{date:"2020-01-01",number:3,count:2},{date:"2020-01-01",number:3,count:2},{date:"2020-01-02",number:4,count:1},{date:"2020-01-02",number:4,count:1}],
             
      groupped = [...src
        .reduce((acc, {date, number, count}) => {
          const group = acc.get(date)
          if(group){
            group.totalNumber += number
            group.totalCount += count
            group.detail.push({date, number, count})
          } else {
            acc.set(
              date,
              {
                date,
                totalNumber: number,
                totalCount: count,
                detail: [{
                  date,
                  number,
                  count
                }]
              }
            )
          }
          return acc
        }, new Map)
        .values()
      ]
        
console.log(groupped)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```